# ¿Cómo evitar que se añadan datos vacios a la basae de datos desde un formulario?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, api, webapi

Yo tengo en el servidor este post donde se crea un perfil a partir de un formulario. He intentado poner ese if pero no me funciona, y aunque no se haya introducido ningún dato se me introduce en la base de datos. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

```
app.post("/api/personal", function (req, res) {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO personal (nombre, apellidos, login, password, area)" + 
    " VALUES ('"+req.body.nombre +"','"+req.body.apellidos+"','"+req.body.login+"','"+req.body.password+"','"
    + req.body.area +"')";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, personal){
        if (req.body.nombre != "" && req.body.apellidos != "" && req.body.login != "" && req.body.password != "" && req.body.area != ""){
            return res.status(201).json(personal);
        }
        if (err){
            res.status(403).send("No se ha podido registrar ");
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Antes del insert comprueva que los datos no esten vacios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como ha comentado Jordi Turell, tu if debería ir antes del insert. Es decir, antes del `connection.query()`. El callback de `connection.query` se ejecutará después de haber ejecutado la sentencia INSERT, por lo tanto ya habrás creado el registro en la base de datos.

Algo como esto debería funcionarte:

```js
app.post("/api/personal", function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.nombre == "" || req.body.apellidos == "" || req.body.login == "" || req.body.password == "" || req.body.area == ""){
        return res.status(403).send("No se ha podido registrar");
    }

    var sql = "INSERT INTO personal (nombre, apellidos, login, password, area)" + 
    " VALUES ('"+req.body.nombre +"','"+req.body.apellidos+"','"+req.body.login+"','"+req.body.password+"','"
    + req.body.area +"')";

    connection.query(sql, function(err, personal){
        if (err){
            res.status(403).send("No se ha podido registrar ");
            return;
        }
        
        return res.status(201).json(personal);
    });
});
```

Otra cosa que deberías tener en cuenta es que deberías evitar usar input de un formulario directamente en tus sentencias SQL porque te arriesgas a ataques de [inyección de SQL](https://www.avast.com/es-es/c-sql-injection#:%7E:text=La%20inyecci%C3%B3n%20de%20SQL%20es,la%20informaci%C3%B3n%20de%20los%20usuarios.). Utiliza [sentencias preparadas](https://www.mejorcodigo.com/p/64600.html) mejor.

Comment: Vale, gracias solucionado. No sabia lo de los ataques de inyección SQL, me enseñaron de esa manera, te agradezco el comentario.